# Clarifying Notation $H : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}, (h_1, \dots, h_n) \mapsto \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i, j = 1}^n b_{ij} h_i h_j$

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, functions, notation

My textbook presents the following lemma:

> **Lemma** $1$ If $B = [b_{ij}]$ is an $n \times n$ real matrix, and if the associated quadratic function
>
> $$H : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}, (h_1, \dots, h_n) \mapsto \dfrac{1}{2} \sum_{i, j = 1}^n b_{ij} h_i h_j$$
>
> is positive-definite, then there is a constant $M > 0$ such that for all $\mathbf{h} \in \mathbb{R}^n$;
>
> $$H(\mathbf{h}) \ge M ||\mathbf{h}||^2$$

I'm unfamiliar with this function notation:

$$H : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}, (h_1, \dots, h_n) \mapsto \dfrac{1}{2} \sum_{i, j = 1}^n b_{ij} h_i h_j$$

1. I am not sure what it means to join the two parts $H : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ and $(h_1, \dots, h_n) \mapsto \dfrac{1}{2} \sum_{i, j = 1}^n b_{ij} h_i h_j$, separated with a comma?
2. The textbook always used the arrow $\to$, such as in $H : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$, but I'm unfamiliar with what the addition of the arrow $\mapsto$ means here? And what is the difference between $\mapsto$ and $\to$?
3. After clarifying the above two points, putting everything in a cohesive picture, what is meant by $$H : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}, (h_1, \dots, h_n) \mapsto \dfrac{1}{2} \sum_{i, j = 1}^n b_{ij} h_i h_j?$$

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to clarify this.

Comment: The notation $(x \mapsto 2x)$ means a function which takes $x$ and multiplies it by $2$. If $f = (x \mapsto 2x)$, then $f(x) = 2x$.

Comment: @Joppy Thanks for the clarification. What is the difference between $\mapsto$ and $\to$?

Comment: The straight arrow is used to specify domain and codomain of a function, like $f: X \to Y$ means that $f$ has domain $X$ and codomain $Y$. So the things on the left and right of the $\to$ arrow must be sets. The things on the left and right of the $\mapsto$ arrow must be elements of those sets. The $\mapsto$ arrow is used when actually defining what the function *does*, as opposed to which sets it goes between.

Comment: @Joppy Ohhhhh, that makes sense! I think I understand it all now! Thanks for the clarification -- AGAIN!! :)

Comment: No worries! The $\mapsto$ arrow is also quite handy for talking about functions without needing to give them a name like $f$ or $g$, for example $(x \mapsto 2x)$ is the doubling function $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, and you could say things like $(x \mapsto \sin x) = \sin$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two parts, separated by a comma, simply say two things:

1. The function $H$ maps from $\mathbb R^n$ to $\mathbb R$. In other words, the domain of $H$ is $\mathbb R^n$ and the codomain of $H$ is $\mathbb R$.
2. For an input $(h_1,\dots, h_n)$, the output of the function is $\dfrac{1}{2} \sum_{i, j = 1}^n b_{ij} h_i h_j$

---

Remember, a function is defined by **three** things: Its domain, codomain and its... let's call it "action".

The fact that the domain and codomain of a function $f$ as $X$ and $Y$ is usually written like so:

$$f: X\to Y$$

while the "action" of the function is written in one of two ways. One is to simply say $$f(x)=\dots,$$ the other is to say $$f:x\mapsto \dots$$ In either way, we write the same thing in the dots.

Answer (score 2):

The first bit defines the domain and the codomain of the function $$H:\mathbb R^n\rightarrow \mathbb R$$ just says that the function $H$ takes as entries elements of $\mathbb R^n$, which are vectors like $(h_1, h_2, \dotso, h_n)$, and **maps** them into elements of $\mathbb R$ which are just numbers. But how does this function map such elements into numbers? You have now to define the explicit form of the function which is the second bit $$(h_1,h_2,\dotso, h_n)\mapsto \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i,j=1}^n b_{ij}h_ih_j$$ which is the same as saying $$H(h_1,h_2,\dotso, h_n)= \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i,j=1}^n b_{ij}h_ih_j$$ So for short $\mapsto$ indicates how the function **maps** certain elements to others, and the symbol $\rightarrow$ indicates from what domain into what codomain the function operates.